# Why is an empty javascript object neither true nor false?

Tags: javascript

In the `NodeJs` console, using a non-strict comparison of an empty object to `true` or `false` I always get `false`. Why?

```
> ({}) == true || ({}) == false
false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're comparing an object to a boolean. That's where things get complicated as you're not using a type-safe comparison.

[Booleans get compared to other types](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) as if they were numbers, i.e. `true` is casted to `1` first and `false` to `0`. Then, when an object is compared to a number, it will be casted [to a primitive value](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) (without a preferred type) - invoking the [`DefaultValue` algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8). On plain objects, this will stringify them, and your empty object [`{}` becomes](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2) `"[object Object]"`, which is neither equal to 0 nor 1.

There are some objects however that will compare as equal to booleans, for example:

```
[0] == false
[1] == true
({toString:function(){return "1"}}) == true
({valueOf:function(){return 0}}) == false
({valueOf:function(){return true}}) == true
```

Comment: To be precise, `[object Object]` will be cast to Number as well (when compared with booleans), becoming `NaN` in process. And `NaN` is obviously incomparable to anything. ) A short rule of thumb: when in doubt, add Strings, compare Numbers. Still, it's better never use `==` when comparing objects and primitives.

Comment: @raina77ow: Yes, depending on what value the `DefaultValue` operation (i.e. the object's `toString`/`valueOf` methods) yields. If that is a string or boolean, it will be parsed to a number to be comparable with `0` or `1`.

Comment: Great explanation. Does this strike anyone else as a problem with JS or am I missing something? Should one !! objects before doing such comparisons? Thanks all.

Comment: No, it's not a problem with JS, it's a problem with abuse of it's dynamic type system. One should not never *need to* compare an object with a boolean. What are you attempting to do anyway?